# Sort python list based on substring in separate list

Tags: python

I have 2 lists..

```
list_a = ['Grapes/testfile.csv','Apples/testfile.csv','Pears/testfile.csv','Pears/testfile2.csv']
ref_list = ['Pears','Grapes','Apples']
```

I need to use `ref_list` list to order `list_a`.

More context, `list_a` will always have the string from `ref_list` before the `/` but the length of `ref_list` will never match that of `list_a`.. Also I dont want to order reverse alphabetically.

Expected Output:

```
ordered_list = ['Pears/testfile.csv','Pears/testfile2.csv','Grapes/testfile.csv','Apples/testfile.csv']
```

I've tried many variations, referencing SO but I cant get this to work.. I just cant work out a way to reference the first list here is my attempt which obviously doesn't work as its not referencing `ref_list` but my logic is to use string method `startswith()`

Something like:?

```
ordered_list = sorted(list_a, key = lambda x: x.startswith())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split()` to extract the word before `/`.

Then use `index()` to get the position of the starting word in `ref_list`, and use that for the sorting key.

```
ordered_list = sorted(list_a, key = lambda x: ref_list.index(x.split('/')[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be the most elegant, but it works:

```
sorted_list = list()

for key in ref_list:
      
   sorted_list += [sorted_value for sorted_value in list_a if \

   sorted_value.startswith(key)]
```